# How to assign a register to an output in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to assign the value of temp to the out.  I searched the web for an answer and tried all kinds of things but still cannot get the output assigned.  Here's the code:

```
module Reg8bit(
    input CLK,
    input En,
    input CLR,
    input [7:0] in,
    output [7:0] out
    );

    reg[7:0] temp;

    always @(posedge CLK)
    begin
        if (En)
        begin
            if (CLR)
                out = 8'b0000_0000;
            else
                out = in;
        end
    end

    assign out = tempQ;

endmodule
```

Edit:  temp should be tempQ, sorry for the typo

Comment: Whats tempQ? You only declared a reg named temp.

Comment: Also, you probably want to write temp <= in inside the else statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant to write

```
module Reg8bit(
    input CLK,
    input En,
    input CLR,
    input [7:0] in,
    output reg [7:0] out // out is a variable, not a wire
    );

    always @(posedge CLK)
    begin
        if (En)
        begin
            if (CLR)
                out <= 8'b0000_0000; // use Non-blocking assignments
            else
                out <= in;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Imho that's what he want to achieve, but it's not what he meant to write ;)

Comment: Why does <= work and = doesn't, isn't the logic contained in the if else clause so why would <= be any different than = after if evaluates to true or false?

Comment: out <= in; means that 'out' will take on the value of 'in' on the next rising edge. out = in means that 'out' will immediately take on the value of 'in' (at least in these circumstances)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense. You are assigning to out twice and your not using your temp register.

You probably meant to write something like this:

```
reg[7:0] temp;

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
    if (En)
    begin
        if (CLR)
            temp <= 0;
        else
            temp <= in;
    end
end

assign out = temp;
```

Its usually (not always) considered good practice to use nonblocking assignments in always blocks. I think in this case you can even do this without the temp register.

Comment: Also `temp <= 8'b0000_0000;`

Answer (score 0):

The LHS of the assign statement should always be a wire. You have declared out as a reg and it's good to use a reg data type in the LHS inside an always block.